# How to tell if an Ember resource is still loading?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember method which fires when when new data arrives:

```
insertDays: function() {
  ...
}.observes('startDate', 'doctor.appointments.length')
```

I want to check to make sure the data is actually there before I execute any heavy code. To do this I currently use:

```
var length = doctor.get('appointments.length')
if (length !== 0) {
    ...
}
```

However, there are occasionally times where there is legitimately no data being handed down from the server, and in this case my !== 0 test fails, and the code doesn't execute when I want it to.

I've tried using the `.isLoaded` method but it always returns `true` regardless.

How do I effectively tell if an Ember resource is still loading?

Comment: isLoaded method should suffice, can you post the code on how do you perform isLoaded ?

Comment: Got it! There's a few things going on here. In my scenario, listening to `.observes('startDate', 'doctor.appointments.isLoaded')` worked perfectly. Elsewhere in the program, addressing `.isLoaded` inside of the function worked as expected (returning false the first time, and true the second). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using `.isLoaded` as an `.observes` property.

The code is now structured as follows and works as expected:

```
insertDays: function() {
  ...
}.observes('startDate', 'doctor.appointments.isLoaded')
```

Elsewhere in the program I was able to use the following code to ascertain whether the data had loaded:

```
var isLoaded = appointments.get('isLoaded');
```

Thanks to @Unspecified for steering me in the right direction. Cheers!